# Alternatives to Unions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, materialized-views

I have a number of schema bound views that I'd like to add indexes to for performance purposes.

The problem is that they have multiple `union all`s in them.

I'm looking for some general refactoring suggestions/approaches to replace the `union all`s with something that would allow index creation on the view.

Basically, there are two logical scenarios for the unions that are being used in the views currently:

1. We have an EntityA which is expressed by the view. The sources for this entity come from many different tables. That is, some EntityAs are recorded in TableA, some are recorded in TableB.
2. We have EntityA which is expressed by the view. TableA sources EntityA. Each row in TableA needs to produce multiple EntityAs in the view.

Thank you.

Comment: It might help to see the SQL you have now so that we can see what needs to be refactored...

Comment: @JeffN825: In scenario 1, are you ever going to see an Entity recorded on TableA and TableB simultaneously?

Comment: @JeffN825: In scenario 2, how does the query determine how many multiple EntityAs are to be returned?

Comment: I figured I'd be asked for some samples. I'm glad to post some shortly, but I'm a bit concerned that they'll obfuscate things, since some of these views are really huge and complex.

Comment: @Mark: Scenario 1 - no, if I'm understanding your question correctly. The view is simply lumping together rows from TableA, B, C with union alls. Each entity/row from the view comes from exactly one of the source tables.

Comment: @Mark: Scenario 2 - Usually this arises in the case of poorly designed legacy tables where multiple values are stuffed into a single field...or when both FieldX AND FieldY are populated for a single row. For example, you have HomeAddressLine1, BusinessAddressLine1, BusinessAddress2Line1, BusinessAddress3Line1. This should result in 4 Address entities in the view.

Comment: Could you provide simplified examples, including table with few samples rows and the union query?

Comment: I was going to suggest a full outer join, but I see from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx that full outer joins are not permitted in indexed views.

Comment: @zmilojko - will do, but it will take me a few hours to put together.

Comment: Is it possible to create separate indexed views for each union part and create an unindexed view to union the results or are the union parts nested affected by grouping or sorting?

Comment: @albin - certainly possible...but I'm not sure if the caller of the unindexed union'd view would reap the performance benefits desired...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is faster or not, but instead of doing the `union all`s can you make a temp table that is indexed the way you want and then insert the values you need from each part of the `union`?